# How do I rectify this switch case error in Ada?

Tags: ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure factor is
    rate: Integer;
begin
    Put("Enter rate: ");
    Get(rate);
  case rate is
   when 1 | 2 =>
      Put("Factor =", factor = 2 * rate - 1);
   when 3 | 5 =>
      Put("Factor =", factor = 3 * rate + 1);
   when 4 =>
      Put("Factor =", factor = 4 * rate - 1);
   when 6 | 7 | 8 =>
      Put("Factor =", factor =  rate - 2);
   when others =>
      Put("Factor =", rate);
end case;
end factor;
```

I am new to ada and im not able to resolve this error. please help me with this code

this is a simple switch case in ada.. this should return factor and rate is the input from user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a comparison of your program and one that compiles and works correctly:

```ada
---------------------------------------------------------------
-- Original program:
--
--  with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
--  procedure factor is
--      rate: Integer;
--  begin
--      Put("Enter rate: ");
--      Get(rate);
--    case rate is
--     when 1 | 2 =>
--        Put("Factor =", factor = 2 * rate - 1);
--     when 3 | 5 =>
--        Put("Factor =", factor = 3 * rate + 1);
--     when 4 =>
--        Put("Factor =", factor = 4 * rate - 1);
--     when 6 | 7 | 8 =>
--        Put("Factor =", factor =  rate - 2);
--     when others =>
--        Put("Factor =", rate);
--  end case;
--  end factor;
------------------------------------------------------------------

with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   rate   : Integer;
   factor : Integer;
begin
   Put ("Enter rate: ");
   Get (rate);

   case rate is
      when 1 | 2 =>
         factor := 2 * rate - 1;
      when 3 | 5 =>
         factor := 3 * rate + 1;
      when 4 =>
         factor := 4 * rate - 1;
      when 6 | 7 | 8 =>
         factor := rate - 2;
      when others =>
         factor := rate;
   end case;
   Put_Line ("Factor =" & factor'Image);
end Main;
```

In Ada I/O procedures and functions are tied to the types being read or written. Therefore, reading an Integer requires an instance of Ada.TextIO.Integer_IO. The predefined package Ada.Integer_Text_IO is just such a package. The Get procedure from that package is used to input the value for the rate variable.

In Ada variables must be declared before they are used and they are only declared in the declarative part of a procedure or function; that is, the part of the procedure or function before the reserved word **begin**. The variable named factor is declared in the declarative part of the procedure main.

The case statement calculates the value of factor based upon the rate input. After the end of the case statement the variable factor has been assigned a value according to the logic in the case statement. It is then output with a trailing newline character using the Put_Line procedure.

The Put_Line procedure requires a single string for its argument. That string is created by concatenating a literal string "Factor =", with the string representation of the value in factor. The 'Image attribute converts the integer value in factor to its corresponding string representation. That string value is concatenated with the literal string forming a single string argument for the Put_Line procedure.

Comment: Variables (and types among other things) can be also declared in declare .. begin .. end; block.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you did not mention the error you got.

I think you got this first

```
factor.adb:8:05: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
factor.adb:8:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-textio.ads:239
factor.adb:8:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-textio.ads:205
factor.adb:8:09: expected type "Standard.String"
factor.adb:8:09: found type "Standard.Integer"
```

If you carefully read, you'll see that the compiler complains about the types. It expected Standard.String and got Standard.Integer.
In fact, you used *Ada.Text_io* which is for text only (cf. [ARM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-1.html)).

As you want to get an integer, you must use the integer version for IO i.e. [Integer_IO](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-8.html).

For displaying, there are several ways but you can use *Integer'Image(my_int)*
to convert your integer to a string.

Then check where the variable factor is declared. In fact, you never declared it but don't even have to do so.

Finally check how you can concatenate two strings, you will be able to join the "Factor =" with the integer converted to string.

Comment: Also, `=` compares the items on its left and right and returns a Boolean; the only `factor` in sight is the name of the procedure, and procedures can’t return anything, which is why the compiler says `error: procedure name cannot be used as operand`. I think OP meant to assign to `factor` and use the result, which is a C thing

Answer (score 0):

When you like to get rate from the user it is good to know what rate is.
From the case statement it looks like a rate type could be declared as -

```
1)   type Rate_Type is 1 .. 8;
2)   type Rate_Type is new Integer range 1 .. 8;
3)   subtype Rate_Type is Integer range 1 .. 8;

     Rate : Rate_Type;
```

In this case (new to Ada) option 3 would be the best option. So now Rate is an Integer in the range from (including) 1 to (including) 8.
To get Rate from the user

```
package Rate_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Rate_Type);
```

The package Rate_IO is like Ada.Integer_Text_IO but for Rate_Type instead of Integer and Rate is input from the user

```
Rate_IO.Get (Rate);
```

The advantage of Rate_IO is that if the user enters a value not in the range of Rate_Type an exception (Data_Error) is raised.
This will cause the program to stop with some message.
It is often a better choice to stop the program than to let it run with a value out of range. At least it makes the program much simpler.
So now that Rate is in range, the `case` statement looks like

```
   case rate is
      when 1 | 2      =>  factor := 2 * rate - 1;
      when 3 | 5      =>  factor := 3 * rate + 1;
      when 4          =>  factor := 4 * rate - 1;
      when 6 | 7 | 8  =>  factor := 1 * rate - 2;
   end case;
```

Below is a program with an exception handler. And uncommented is an example with a default value for rate.

```
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
with ada.integer_text_io;

procedure program_2 is

   subtype rate_t is integer range 1 .. 8;

   package rate_io is new ada.text_io.integer_io (rate_t);

   rate   : rate_t;
   factor : integer;
begin

   --  Input
   put ("Enter rate: ");
   rate_io.get (rate);    -- May raise data_error exception

   --  Calculate
   case rate is
      when 1 | 2      =>  factor := 2 * rate - 1;
      when 3 | 5      =>  factor := 3 * rate + 1;
      when 6 | 7 | 8  =>  factor := 1 * rate - 2;
      when 4          =>  factor := 1 * rate + 0;
   end case;

   --  Output
   put ("factor =");
   ada.integer_text_io.put (factor);
   new_line;

   --  Error handling
exception when data_error =>
   put_line ("rate out of range");

end program_2;

   -- Put begin/exception/end block around rate_io.get to
   -- provide ie a default value:
   --
   -- begin
   --    rate_io.get (rate);
   -- exception when data_error =>
   --    rate := rate_t'first;  -- A default value
   -- end;
```